# not able to get tag from id in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to get the value of the `id` in html using jquery but not able to get that value

```
<div id="tar">...</div>
<div id="tar" class="helper">...</div>
```

the script is here

```
<script>
       console.log(($('#tar').html());
       console.log(($('#tar'));
   </script>
```

thank you in advance!

Comment: HTML 101: IDs __must__ be unique within a document.

Comment: Val is for input. Try .html()

Comment: i dont have anything with `val()` . i changed to html still its not working

Comment: Can you please update the question with your new logic that is not working.  And can you explicity state what value you are trying to log?  Are you trying to log what is inside the tag (the '...' as you have it now)?

Comment: Right now your code is invalid. You have an extra open parenthesis (`(`) after `console.log`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant use the same id value twice . Id should be unique for each tag. Give a unique id or get the value via className.
Please change it

Comment: yes it is working with unique id. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `val()` method is used to get the value attribute of the element. If you want to return the contents enclosed in the tag use the following:

```
 console.log(($('#tar').html())
```

If you are looking to get the value of a particular attribute such as the `id` you could use the following:

```
element.attr("id");
```

You also might want to make sure the `id` attributes you use are unique, otherwise change them to the `class` attribute. If you do this make sure you handle the selection of multiple elements though.

For example:

```
$('.tar').each(function(i, obj) {

    console.log((obj.html());

});
```

Comment: This answer ignores the duplicate id issue.

Comment: The `tar` id is used twice .it should be unique . So may be this is the error

Comment: @Taplar Ya you are right I added an explanation for that.

Comment: Ths OP clearly stated they want the ID, not the contents. Also, divs have no value attribute, only form elements do.

Comment: @j08691 I find it a little strange that they would both want to select based on and return the `id`, so I am not 100% sure what they are looking for. I have included an example of how you could return the value of a particular attribute however.